# Is "grid-deduction" needed here?

Tags: support, tags

Is "[grid-deduction](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid-deduction)" needed [here](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/89362/find-the-hidden-message-in-this-weird-array/89363#89363)?

Comment: I think that depends on how the puzzle actually works, which (presumably deliberately) you haven't yet said. Once it's solved, it'll be more apparent what tags were needed :-).

Answer (score 2):

From the current answers, the most recent of which seems to be a correct solution to the puzzle, it appears not.

Tags have descriptions (you can read them by hovering over a tag in a tag list, or by clicking a tag and reading the description at the top of the page; the descriptions are also shown below each tag in the popup box that appears when you're adding or editing a question's tags).  These are often helpful in understanding what *we* mean by a particular tag name.  "Grid deduction" is not just "figuring out" (deduction) the meaning of a block of things arranged in a "grid"-like pattern; it is used specifically for a type of puzzle solved by logically applying a set of constraints to elements of a grid. Sudoku is an example most people are familiar with.

Your puzzle isn't solved in this manner. I think the tags you applied are the correct ones.
([cipher](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cipher) is debatable; I'd probably not include it.)